# Install a feature according to a user input

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I have 2 features.

1. Network Device.
2. USB Device.

And i need them to install, one at a time. Customize dialog allows to install both features at one time, which i wanted to avoid, so I removed the "Customize" Dialog (I am using "WixUI_Mondo") and I added a custom dialog with 2 radio buttons.

```
<Control Id ="ConnectionType" Type="RadioButtonGroup" Property="CONPROPERTY" X="20" Y="60" Width="330" Height="100" Text="test">
  <RadioButtonGroup Property="CONPROPERTY">
    <RadioButton Text="!(loc.ChooseConnectionTypeDevice)" Value="network" Height="18" Width="370" X="0" Y="20" />
    <RadioButton Text="!(loc.ChooseConnectionTypeUSB)" Value="usb" Height="18" Width="370" X="0" Y="40" />
  </RadioButtonGroup>
</Control>
```

Now I want to install above features according to the selection of the radio buttons.

I tried adding a condition to my features. but it seems it is not working. I guess this is not working at run time.

```
<Feature Id='NetworkDevice' Level="1"> 

<ComponentRef Id='cmpConfig' />
<ComponentRef Id='cmpCatalog' />

<Condition Level="0"><![CDATA[CONPROPERTY<>"network"]]></Condition>
</Feature>

<Feature Id='UsbDevice' Level="1">
<ComponentRef Id='cmpConfig' />
<ComponentRef Id='cmpCatalog' />
<ComponentRef Id='cmpUsbInstallation' />

<Condition Level='0'><![CDATA[CONPROPERTY<>"usb"]]></Condition>
</Feature>
```

How could i achieve this scenario. can any one show me a path?

Comment: Look at the logs and check what value is `CONPROPERTY` getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work the way you expect. The 'Condition' references in the code end up authoring MSI Condition Table entires. These are evaluated before your UI ever pops up. What you want is 'Publish' ControlEvents that will turn the features on/off when the user clicks the "Next" button. Something like this:

```
<Publish Dialog="YourDialog" Control="Next" Event="AddLocal" Value="NetworkDevice" Order="1">![CDATA[CONPROPERTY=network]]</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="YourDialog" Control="Next" Event="Remove" Value="NetworkDevice" Order="2">![CDATA[CONPROPERTY<>network]]</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="YourDialog" Control="Next" Event="AddLocal" Value="UsbDevice" Order="3">![CDATA[CONPROPERTY=usb]]</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="YourDialog" Control="Next" Event="Remove" Value="UsbDevice" Order="4">![CDATA[CONPROPERTY<>usb]]</Publish>
```